# Getting domain host name in ruby

Tags: ruby, uri, host

Is there a possible way to get the domain's hostname in ruby?

For example:

```
$ host api.heroku.com
api.heroku.com is an alias for api-default.herokussl.com.
api-default.herokussl.com is an alias for elb027033-298234319.us-east-1.elb.amazonaws.com.
elb027033-298234319.us-east-1.elb.amazonaws.com has address 23.23.76.65
elb027033-298234319.us-east-1.elb.amazonaws.com has address 23.21.240.208
elb027033-298234319.us-east-1.elb.amazonaws.com has address 107.22.242.236
```

host would be the best example, because it'll also show if the domain/subdomain is pointing to another host like amazonAWS or etc.

Comment: [`Resolv`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.2/libdoc/resolv/rdoc/Resolv.html) - the docs even have some nice examples.

Comment: Which docs? I tried a few things with Resolv but not as useful as executing  `host domain.com` command from ruby.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> not as useful as executing `host domain.com` command from ruby

I beg to differ... (but it does involve knowing what data you want, and how DNS works).

```
require 'resolv'

def host(address)
  Resolv::DNS.open do |dns|
    loop do
      ress = dns.getresources address, Resolv::DNS::Resource::IN::CNAME
      break if ress.empty?
      canonical_name = ress.first.name.to_s
      puts "#{address} is an alias for #{canonical_name}"
      address = canonical_name
    end

    ress = dns.getresources address, Resolv::DNS::Resource::IN::A
    addresses = ress.each do |r|
      puts "#{address} has address #{r.address.to_s}"
    end
  end
  return
end

host("api.heroku.com")
```

Comment: Wow! that's exactly what I was looking for! Thanks.